# Facebook app: Access token expires with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: python, ajax, facebook, xmlhttprequest, flask

Edit 2: When the token fails oauth gives `{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}`

Edit: This is also occasionally occurring during normal page navigation.

My facebook user access tokens are expiring the second time I use XMLHttpRequest. The access tokens are not expiring when I navigate within the app otherwise. I am using a python Flask app with Heroku. When a page loads it gets the token with `get_token`:

```
def fbapi_get_string(path,
    domain=u'graph', params=None, access_token=None,
    encode_func=urllib.urlencode):
    """Make an API call"""

    if not params:
        params = {}
    params[u'method'] = u'GET'
    if access_token:
        params[u'access_token'] = access_token

    for k, v in params.iteritems():
        if hasattr(v, 'encode'):
            params[k] = v.encode('utf-8')

    url = u'https://' + domain + u'.facebook.com' + path
    params_encoded = encode_func(params)
    url = url + params_encoded
    result = requests.get(url).content

    return result


def fbapi_auth(code):
    params = {'client_id': app.config['FB_APP_ID'],
              'redirect_uri': request.url,
              'client_secret': app.config['FB_APP_SECRET'],
              'code': code}

    result = fbapi_get_string(path=u"/oauth/access_token?", params=params,
                              encode_func=simple_dict_serialisation)
    print result
    pairs = result.split("&", 1)
    result_dict = {}
    for pair in pairs:
        (key, value) = pair.split("=")
        result_dict[key] = value
    return (result_dict["access_token"], result_dict["expires"])
def get_token():

    if request.args.get('code', None):
        return fbapi_auth(request.args.get('code'))[0]

    cookie_key = 'fbsr_{0}'.format(FB_APP_ID)

    if cookie_key in request.cookies:

        c = request.cookies.get(cookie_key)
        encoded_data = c.split('.', 2)

        sig = encoded_data[0]
        data = json.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(str(encoded_data[1]) + (64-len(encoded_data[1])%64)*"="))

        if not data['algorithm'].upper() == 'HMAC-SHA256':
            raise ValueError('unknown algorithm {0}'.format(data['algorithm']))

        h = hmac.new(FB_APP_SECRET, digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
        h.update(encoded_data[1])
        expected_sig = urlsafe_b64encode(h.digest()).replace('=', '')

        if sig != expected_sig:
            raise ValueError('bad signature')

        params = {
            'client_id': FB_APP_ID,
            'client_secret': FB_APP_SECRET,
            'redirect_uri': '',
            'code': data['code']
        }

        from urlparse import parse_qs
        r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token', params=params)
        token = parse_qs(r.content).get('access_token')
        return token
```

`None` is returned from `get_token` when there is no token. When `None` is returned or if the user has not given the appropriate permissions `redirect(oauthLoginUrl())` is called:

```
def oauthLoginUrl():
    fb_login_uri = ("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"
                    "?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s" %
                    (app.config['FB_APP_ID'], request.url))

    if app.config['FBAPI_SCOPE']:
        fb_login_uri += "&scope=%s" % ",".join(app.config['FBAPI_SCOPE'])
    return fb_login_uri
```

This seems to work for the pages navigated in the browser but for XMLHttpRequests the token expires. The response for these Ajax requests gives an error code instead of the redirect when the token has expired. The user is told that their session has expired and is asked to refresh the page.

Does anyone have any ideas about why the tokens are expiring with Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

The oauth code cannot be used more than once. The heroku template is outdated. Replace the `get_token()` function with:

```
def get_token():

    if request.args.get('code', None):
        token = fbapi_auth(request.args.get('code'))
        session['accessToken'] = token[0]
        session['expiry'] = time.time() + int(token[1])
        return token[0]

    # Check if we have the token already and that it has not expired
    if 'accessToken' in session:
        if session['expiry'] < time.time():
            return None
        return session['accessToken']

    cookie_key = 'fbsr_{0}'.format(FB_APP_ID)

    if cookie_key in request.cookies:

        c = request.cookies.get(cookie_key)
        encoded_data = c.split('.', 2)

        sig = encoded_data[0]
        data = json.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(str(encoded_data[1]) + (64-len(encoded_data[1])%64)*"="))

        if not data['algorithm'].upper() == 'HMAC-SHA256':
            raise ValueError('unknown algorithm {0}'.format(data['algorithm']))

        h = hmac.new(FB_APP_SECRET, digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
        h.update(encoded_data[1])
        expected_sig = urlsafe_b64encode(h.digest()).replace('=', '')

        if sig != expected_sig:
            raise ValueError('bad signature')

        params = {
            'client_id': FB_APP_ID,
            'client_secret': FB_APP_SECRET,
            'redirect_uri': '',
            'code': data['code']
        }

        from urlparse import parse_qs
        r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token', params=params)
        token = parse_qs(r.content).get('access_token')
        if token:
            # Save token
            session['accessToken'] = token;
            session['expiry'] = time.time() + int(parse_qs(r.content).get('expires'))
        return token
```